# How to set multiple selection in treeView?

Tags: python, pyqt

i have treeView based on QAbstractItemModel, but now i don't know how to set multiple selection in my model

Comment: Your question needs more detail. Please supply some code, the libraries you are using and some evidence that you have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are going to want to do this programmatically?

Firstly, selections are not controlled by the model, but by the view. This is because a model can be connected to multiple views, each of which can have a different selection (the views are independent, except for the data they show from the model).

Ayway, you will want to get the "selection Model" from the treeview

`selection_model = treeview.selectionModel()`

And then you can call

```
selection_model.select(model_index,QItemSelectionModel.SelectCurrent)
```

repeatedly to select what ever items you like, based on the `model_index` specified (you can find the index of a row for a QStandardItem() by calling `indexFromItem(item)` on the **data** model (not the selection model).

Anyway, I suggest you look up the documentation for treeview selectionModels as this will help you further (can't really help much more without more information than a single line question!)

Comment: in my quetion i mean: to select two and more rows in a time by a CTRL or Shift, thanks anyway